# Is it the crystal / quartz?

Tags: pcb, oscillator, repair

I have a simple gadget (called "Fridgezoo") that talks when the fridge stays open. I always hated it, but my sentiments are with it (hey, it talks!) so I want to repair it.

What's the problem? It forgets the time. Normally, you set the time by a long button press, which tells it that it's morning. But it forgets it, and always talks like it's morning.

So I opened it up, hoping to see some parts numbers.

Overview images front and back:

[image]

[image]

As it's a timing problem, I suspect the crystal could have gone defect.

That would be this part on the PCB:

[image]

On the other side of the PCB, all looks fine to the eye (under a microscope, actually.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I still believe it's the crystal oscillator. But what value? There is nothing visible on it.

Comment: Doubtful. Is there a battery in there somewhere too?

Comment: if the oscillator went bad, the microcontroller won't be able to do anything at all. if the device has any normal functionality, i'd say the oscillator is fine

Comment: It looks like the manufacturer never cleaned the PCB, which over time could cause reliability issues. Agree with above comment that it is unlikely the crystal has gone bad and more likely a power issue.

Comment: thanks to all! There are 2 AAA-batteries attached, so 2.4V nominal. Should I clean the PCB with alcohol and eartips?

Comment: Your second and fourth pictures look identical. Was there a different fourth picture that you intended to show us? And while @ChrisFernandez's comment is valid, it's possible that the chip uses an internal oscillator to run the CPU and only uses the external crystal for the real-time clock.

Comment: @RaphaelJeger, you need to soak the entire board into Isopropyl Alcohol 99%, use a brush (toothbrush is OK) to remove all residues, and dry it well. No eartips.

Comment: @DaveTweed thanks! Just exchanged them... on your comment, that would mean it could still be the external crystal?

Comment: Your extreme closeups are really not all that helpful. Could you post pictures of the entire front and back sides of the board instead?

Comment: @crj11: What you're calling residue looks more to me like a (poor) attempt at conformal coating. After all, in this application, a certain amount of condensation is to be expected.

Comment: @DaveTweed just added some overviews, thanks for the input!

Comment: Much better. It becomes obvious that the crystal is not in fact connected to the MPU, but rather to a separate 8-pin chip, which is probably the RTC. So yes, the crystal is more likely to be the culprit than the chip, although the latter may have suffered ESD and stopped working on its own.

Comment: I have now cleaned the PCB with alcohol. Was quite easy to get that thing off. If it's the crystal, how can I know / guestimate it's frequency?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger, it is very likely that the crystal is the standard 32kHz clock crystal. The processor might operate on its own internal oscillator, but the time likely comes from this external RTC. You need to probe the other pin row (pins 5-6-7 of the 8-pin chip to see if it generates anything. It is extremely unlikely to have a damaged crystal. The typical RTC crystal clock has very high-impedance connections and is very sensitive to moisture, you need to dry the board thoroughly, with hairdryer.

Comment: Guys, it seems we have success! I cleaned the PCB with Isopropanol and a small brush, dried it with the hairdryer (heat gun could've been to hot I feared) - and it works again! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely the crystal. It's hard to see from your photos, but it looks like the micro-controller is powered from the battery through a CDS cell and then a capacitor. So I'd guess that the micro-controller is meant to go into a micro-power mode and survive from either the leakage current through the CDS cell, or the energy stored in the capacitor.

I'd try first replacing C1 with a new capacitor that can cope with low temperatures and is low leakage, and failing that check the CDS cell isn't looking burned up.

Others have said the board looks like it's not been cleaned, however I think that's probably a conformal coating to cope with operating in a condensing atmosphere.

It'll probably emit nasty fumes and you stab through it with a soldering iron, and you'll very likely want to put something back when you're done. Acrylic nail polish is cheap and works, or use a can of proper electronic conformal coating.